# How to get array details another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have category array. there are more products. 
I need show categories in category page. 
when click on a category, I have to redirect the product page and show the necessary products. 
When click on a product, I have to redirect the product_details page and show the necessary product details.

**category loaded to the category page, when click on that it will redirect the product page. But, I cant see products. 
And how to create product_details.html page also.**

I have to show like this :

- category page : term_id, name
- product page : post_title,  ID
- product details page : post_title, post_date, post_author, ID

**categorylist-product.json**

```
{
"category": [{
    "term_id": "10",
    "name": "Arden Grange",
    "slug": "arden-grange",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "47",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange, Premium",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 16:13:04",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "50",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Puppy\/Junior Large Breed",
        "post_date": "2015-10-21 04:56:23",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "53",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Weaning\/Puppy",
        "post_date": "2015-10-22 12:52:35",
        "post_author": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "term_id": "8",
    "name": "Menu 1",
    "slug": "menu-1",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "38",
        "post_title": "Home",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:43:44",
        "post_author": "1"
    }, {
        "ID": "30",
        "post_title": "",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:13:56",
        "post_author": "1"
    }, {
        "ID": "31",
        "post_title": "",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:13:57",
        "post_author": "1"
    }]
}]
}
```

**CategoryController.js**

```
app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope','category', function($scope, category) {


category.success(function(data) {
     $scope.userslists = data;
  });
}]);
```

**ProductController.js**

```
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'category', function($scope, $routeParams, category,products) {


category.success(function(data) {
$scope.users = data.category[$routeParams.id];


});
}]);
```

**category.js (Service file)**

```
app.factory('category', ['$http', function($http) { 

return $http.get('http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php')

       .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

**category.html**

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content scroll="true" has-bouncing="false" class="has-header nk-colorGrey">
<div class="users" ng-repeat="users in userslists.category | filter:searchBox">
<a href="#/{{$index}}" style="text-decoration:none;">

    <ion-item    class="item widget uib_w_109 d-margins item-button-right" data-uib="ionic/list_item_button" data-ver="0">{{ users.name }} {{ users.post_title }}
        <label style="display:none;">{{ users.term_id }}</label>

        <form method="POST" style="display:none;">
            <input type="SUBMIT"  name="search" value="{{ users.term_id }}" />
            <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="search" />
        </form>

        <button class="button button-balanced button-clear">
            <i class="icon ion-arrow-graph-up-right ion"></i>
        </button>
    </ion-item>

    <!--h2 class="name"> {{ users.age }} </h2-->


</a>
</div>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**users.html (this is product.html page)**

```
<ion-view>

<ion-content scroll="true" has-bouncing="false" class="has-header nk-colorGrey">

<div class="users-detail">
<h2 class="users-name"> {{ users.name }} </h2>
<h2 class="name"> {{ product-post_title }} </h2>
<h2 class="users-name"> {{ users.name }} </h2>

  <h2 class="name"> {{ users.term_id }} </h2>
  <h2 class="name"> {{ users.term_id }} </h2>

</div>

</ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('LookApp', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngRoute']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

.when('/', {
controller: 'CategoryController',
templateUrl: 'views/category.html'
  })

 .when('/:id', {
controller: 'ProductController',
templateUrl: 'views/users.html'
  })

.when('/login/:friendId', {
controller: 'LoginController',
templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
  })
.otherwise({
redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like this 
*category page*

```
<div class="users" ng-repeat="users in userslists.category | filter:searchBox track by $index" ng-click="save($index)">
```

*controllers.js*

```
app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, category) {
$http.get('http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php')
       .success(function(data) { 
           $scope.userslists = data;
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
    $scope.save() = function(index) {
        $rootScope.index = index;
    }
}]);
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', function() {

}]);
```

*product page*

```
<div class="users-detail">
<h2 class="users-name"> {{ userslists[index].category.name }} </h2>
<h2 class="name"> {{ userslists[index].category.products.post_title }} </h2>
<h2 class="users-name"> {{ userslists[index].category.name }} </h2>
<h2 class="name"> {{ userslists[index].category.term_id }} </h2>
<h2 class="name"> {{  userslists[index].category.term_id }} </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Before entering anything in product page just try {{index}} in product page after in ion-content. If you get value of index there then this would work for you. It is a simple trick I have used in my code. Wish that It would work for you too.

Comment: what controller.js i need change my friend. please tell me

Comment: See all you need to do is that first put your json data in $scope, which you have done already. Then get data in html as you are getting it in category page. Now to go to the specific category's product you need to save the $index value of that list in variable As in *$rootscope* And get it in product page.