# Json array details show in three pages in angularjs with ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have category array. there are more products. 
I need show categories in category page. 
when click on a category, I have to redirect the product page and show the necessary products. 
When click on a product, I have to redirect the product_details page and show the necessary product details.

**category loaded to the category page, when click on that it will redirect the product page. But, I cant see products. 
And what are the errors of these controllers, and how to create "product_details.html", and "product.html" page also.**

I have to show like this :

- category page : term_id, name
- product page : post_title,  ID
- product details page : post_title, post_date, post_author, ID

**categorylist-product.json**

```
{
"category": [{
    "term_id": "10",
    "name": "Arden Grange",
    "slug": "arden-grange",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "47",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange, Premium",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 16:13:04",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "50",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Puppy\/Junior Large Breed",
        "post_date": "2015-10-21 04:56:23",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "53",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Weaning\/Puppy",
        "post_date": "2015-10-22 12:52:35",
        "post_author": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "term_id": "8",
    "name": "Menu 1",
    "slug": "menu-1",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "38",
        "post_title": "Home",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:43:44",
        "post_author": "1"
    }, {
        "ID": "30",
        "post_title": "",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:13:56",
        "post_author": "1"
    }, {
        "ID": "31",
        "post_title": "",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:13:57",
        "post_author": "1"
    }]
}]
}
```

**CategoryController.js**

```
app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope','category', function($scope, category) {

 category.success(function(data) {
     $scope.userslists = data;
});

}]);
```

**ProductController.js**

```
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'category', function($scope, $routeParams, category,products) {

category.success(function(data) {
$scope.users = data.category[$routeParams.id];

});
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('LookApp', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngRoute']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

.when('/', {
controller: 'CategoryController',
templateUrl: 'views/category.html'
})

.when('/:id', {
controller: 'ProductController',
templateUrl: 'views/users.html'
})
 .when('/login/:friendId', {
controller: 'LoginController',
templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
})

.otherwise({
redirectTo: '/'

});
```

**category.js (Service file)**

```
app.factory('category', ['$http', function($http) {    

return $http.get('http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php')


       .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

Comment: you need to put *userslists* in category,product and details pages

Comment: I have to put data like this : 
" category page : term_id, name" .  
" product page : post_title, ID ". 
" product details page : post_title, post_date, post_author, ID "

Comment: do you want to show all data or only that particular term_id's details in other pages ??

Comment: only the particular term_id's details my friend.

Answer (score 0):

see you have put your data in $scope.userlists so when you call your data in html then you need to do like this 
*category page*

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userslists">
Term ID : {{user.category.term_id}}
Name    : {{user.category.name}}
</div>
```

*product page*

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userslists">
Post Title : {{user.category.products.post_title}}
ID         : {{user.category.products.ID}}
</div>
```

*Details page*

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userslists">
Post Title : {{user.category.products.post_title}}
Post Date  : {{user.category.products.post_date}}
Post Author: {{user.category.products.post_author}}
ID         : {{user.category.products.ID}}
</div>
```

Comment: not worked this code my friend. how to change the controllers.

Comment: Are you getting any data in controllers.js in $scope.userslists? And the json data you are getting is it in http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103142/how-to-get-array-details-another-page... Can you answer this question. this is my full question my friend.

Comment: I getting this data from mysql DB using category.js (Service file). Categories will load to the category page. when click on the category, it will go to the product page also, but can't load the products.