# Nested json array data, how to get selected data into the another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

**This is my json file. I attached two pictures below this code. After that click on the product, I need to show all details of clicked product. This is my another link

[How to get array details another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103142/how-to-get-array-details-another-page/37108830?noredirect=1#comment61765443_37108830)

How to get selected product data into the another page. 
**

```
{
"category": [{
    "term_id": "10",
    "name": "Arden Grange",
    "slug": "arden-grange",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "47",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange, Premium",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 16:13:04",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "50",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Puppy\/Junior Large Breed",
        "post_date": "2015-10-21 04:56:23",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "53",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Weaning\/Puppy",
        "post_date": "2015-10-22 12:52:35",
        "post_author": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "term_id": "12",
    "name": "Jewellery",
    "slug": "jewellery",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "59",
        "post_title": "Sterling silver Amethyst studs",
        "post_date": "2015-11-30 09:37:05",
        "post_author": "8"
    }, {
        "ID": "105",
        "post_title": "London Blue topaz 7 carat AAA quality",
        "post_date": "2015-12-01 05:09:32",
        "post_author": "8"
    }, {
        "ID": "134",
        "post_title": "7 Carat Natural Purple Amethyst AAA quality",
        "post_date": "2015-12-01 05:09:31",
        "post_author": "8"
    }, {
        "ID": "136",
        "post_title": "10 carat natural Smoky Quartz AAA quality",
        "post_date": "2015-12-01 05:09:31",
        "post_author": "8"
    }]
}]
}
```

**Category**
[image]

**Product**
[image]

Comment: You can set your product detail json data as a rootScope variable and then pass product id to another page. fetch product detail of that id from rootScope variable in your controller

Comment: can you put code in here.

Comment: You can try yourself

Comment: this is my code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103142/how-to-get-array-details-another-page/37108830?noredirect=1#comment61765443_37108830

Comment: Are you talking about that code